# Excel data read using C#

Tags: c#, excel

Excel data Reading using C# 
but the value comes under formula

ex: A2 cell value 63

```
=Sum(54,9) =>63
```

This 63 value store one local variable using c#

What I have tried:

I'm using this one, the value comes `-2141400` (Negative value coming)

```
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = -2141400
```

I want this `xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = 63`

can any one help us ?